# How to terminate Google Colab correctly?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I found

## !kill -9 -1

it seems not working correctly.

When I do many tasks simultaneously on colab,
popup appears and asks me like this,

"Memory usage is close to the limit. terminate other? "

and after click yes, GPU gets much faster,
seems initialized correctly.

My question is,
how to call that popup by myself.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Which pop up are you referring to? Also please explain what you do with `!kill -9 -1` or where you found it. From where do you want to call that pop up? Do you want to close an application programmatically? Please clarify.

Comment: Just to elaborate: Colab normally runs things in the Google cloud. So `kill` or similar commands to kill things on your end doesn't do what you need. Hence the advice to interact with colab to stop things on the Google end.

Answer (score 8):

To see a list of running sessions along with the memory allocated to them and an option to terminate, follow these instructions.

1. Make sure notebook is connected to an active runtime.
2. Click on "Runtime" in the menu bar.
3. Clink on "Manage sessions" in the menu that appears.
4. The window that pops up lists your active sessions.

[image: notebook]
[image: menu]
[image: active_sessions]

Comment: Could you also tell what this "Ram used" section here specifies? Is it our current RAM being accumulated?

Comment: I have checked it and I have only one active session! This is a very strict limitation! Only 1!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
from google.colab import runtime
runtime.unassign()
```

runtime.unassign() command place at the end of your script. It will disconnect and delete runtime.